# How do I access a remote mail directory from my Android?

Tags: email

The directory is on a remote server. I can read the mail using mutt in a shell but I want to use an app on my Android that can render HTML.

Any suggestions?

MailDir format

Comment: Does the server provides an email access protocol like IMAP or POP3?

Comment: Nonsense. This is not an Android question.

Comment: DavidPostill migrates every question that contains a sentence like "I want to use an app on my Android" to the Android Stackexchange site.

Answer (score 0):

The standard method for remotely accessing Maildir inboxes is IMAP.

Set up an IMAP server on your remote machine (e.g. Dovecot/Cyrus/Courier), then install an IMAP-capable Android mail app (e.g. K-9 or Gmail).

Practically all such mail apps support HTML body parts.

Comment: Can I setup Dovecot without a Postfix server?

Comment: Dovecot doesn't really care about Postfix or SMTP. Android mail apps will ask for an SMTP server address though, but you can fill in any random address instead.

Comment: Yes, but the clients want to authenticate to an SMTP server. I just want to read the mail from a MailDir directory on a remote host

Comment: They'll do fine without authenticating. Go through "Manual setup", for example, and switch the SMTP side to "no authentication required". (Or try specifying an SMTP server of _another_ provider – as long as you don't actually send mail, it won't matter.) In the worst case, set up OpenSMTPd or something else that only lets you auth and nothing else.

Comment: Okay. Not all clients seem to offer "no authentication" but I found one. I cannot connect connect to Dovecot. I'm sure I haven't got it in figured right but I'll keep plugging at it

Comment: This is not really an Android question. Don't know why it was moved here